# How to check if client computer is running a 32-bit or 64-bit OS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, 32bit-64bit

How to check if client computer is running a 32-bit or 64-bit OS in ASP.NET 3.5?

Comment: Which computer? Your ASP.NET application's server or the user's?

Comment: Presumably he means the server, if he was running c# on the client he'd have tagged it silverlight.

Comment: @JonB: In fact, OP mentioned *client* computer

Comment: @abatishchev Oh duh, too early for me.. :(

Comment: What transferred to client browsers is nothing but html documents/Javascripts. AFAIK you can't get the OS information via js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to reliably determine whether a client runs a 64 bit operating system or a 32 bit one. What if the client is not a full blown computer at all?

All you can do without running any platform specific code on the client is to trust the user agent string passed by the browser. Some browsers, like Internet Explorer, do in fact send this clue in the user agent string.

For instance, 64-bit IE will send "Win64; x64" as part of the user agent string and 32-bit IE running on a 64-bit edition of Windows will send "WOW64" as part of it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
```

There are other native Win32 API which can determine the same:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: This will get you environment of the server side which is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: +1 to offset negative - to be fair, at the time this answer was posted, the question didn't specify that, so this was a valid answer until the question was changed

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx)

It will return true if the operating system is 64-bit; otherwise, false.

Comment: Without judging the correctness of you answer (it even looks like you may be correct) I'd like to say that one-word posts are rather seldom very helpful. At least, provide references etc. I'm not trying to be mean, I am just trying to tell you what the community most often expect from answers.

Comment: This is a .net 4 and above only. The poster is limited to 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the user agent to see what OS/Architecture the client is running on, but the user agent can be modified so isn't a 100% reliable source.

Look at http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ to see what yours is, mine is showing WOW64:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/11.0.696.65 Safari/534.24

Other than that you may have to run some script on the client to determine what it is - looking for the environment "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE" you're again relying on that variable being present; in a potentially sandboxed environment, the broswer (or app) may not want you to see many environmental variables.

What's the reason for determining the OS 32/64bit architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You can try displaying first the Server Variables for ASP.NET, like this:

```
       if (!IsPostBack) {
            int loop1, loop2;
            NameValueCollection coll;

            // Load ServerVariable collection into NameValueCollection object.
            coll = Request.ServerVariables;
            // Get names of all keys into a string array. 
            String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys;
            for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) {
                Response.Write("Key: " + arr1[loop1] + "<br>");
                String[] arr2 = coll.GetValues(arr1[loop1]);
                for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < arr2.Length; loop2++) {
                    Response.Write("Value " + loop2 + ": " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[loop2]) + "<br>");
                }
            }
        }
```

After that you can check the HTTP_USER_AGENT value:

> Key: HTTP_USER_AGENT
>   Value 0: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; **WOW64**; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2; Zune 4.7; AskTbFXTV5/5.11.3.15590)

As per this **[link](http://www.useragentstring.com/Internet%20Explorer8.0_id_14426.php)**, it means:

> (Windows-On-Windows 64-bit) A 32-bit application is running on a 64-bit processor

Comment: Not 100% reliable though, the client may disguise/modify the user agent to not have WOW64 in the string, or even say it's WOW64 when it is in fact a 32bit machine.